# Declaring objects in services in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I was trying a code to put a value in html page from angular js controller which is injected with a service.

I create an object in the service and add some value as property to this object. Next i read this value in the controller.

Now what i am observing is that the name of the service and name of the object should be same, only then the value is coming properly else not.

Following is the HTML code:-

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>AngularJS Services</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="Addition as add">
    <p>{{ add.num }}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Following is the working code:-

abc.js

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);
angular.module('myApp').factory('number',function(){
var number={};
number.val=10;
return number;
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('Addition',function(number){

var self=this;
self.num=number.val;
});
```

Following is the code which is not working:-

```
angular.module('myApp',[]);
angular.module('myApp').factory('number',function(){
var num={};
num.val=10;
return num;
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('Addition',function(number){

var self=this;
self.num=num.val;
});
```

Is is mandatory that service name and the object name should be same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a small error. It should be:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('Addition',function(number){

var self=this;
self.num=number.val;
});
```

Comment: this is when i declare object with name number, which is working fine. But when i declare num it is not working.

angular.module('myApp',[]);
angular.module('myApp').factory('number',function(){
var num={};
num.val=10;
return num;
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('Addition',function(number){

var self=this;
self.num=num.val;
});

Answer (score 1):

That's because num is undefined in your function

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('Addition',function( number ){

    var self=this;
        self.num = num.val;
});
```

All you are getting is a reference to num in your controller.

'number' is just the name of your factory. Hence, the above code will not work.

You'll have to use.

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('Addition',function(number){

    var self=this;
    self.num = number.val;
});
```